# Issue creating virtualenv, sys.prefix should be something else?

Tags: python, installation, homebrew

I need help setting up `virtualenv`? I installed successfully (running `sudo pip install virtualenv`), but when I try to create one (typing `virtualenv venv` in the directory I want one to be created), I get this output:

> "Using base prefix '/Users/kristinho/anaconda3'
>
> New python executable in /Users/kristinho/iOS/MyProj/venv/bin/python
>
> ERROR: The executable /Users/kristinho/iOS/MyProj/venv/bin/python is
>   not functioning
>
> ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/kristinho/iOS/MyProj' (should
>   be '/Users/kristinho/iOS/MyProj/venv')
>
> ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable"

I have a strong feeling it has something to do with `Python` versions and installing `virtualenv` caused another version of python to be installed over the one I already had. But I'm not sure because installations are mysterious. I looked inside something and found a folder `venv`.

I have `Python 3.4.4` installed via `anaconda`. I have the latest `virtualenv` installed. I tried to brew install python to have `2.7`, which seemed like it might help based on some googling, but had issues installing that.

Comment: Paste *specific* error messages.

Comment: edited, accidentally posted before finishing

Comment: Not to say your question is bad, but I'm no OS X person and it seems that this issue has been encountered on OS X before.  You may be able to get further there.

Comment: My confusion is that the sys.prefix seems to be expecting something only off by one folder. I've tried numerous suggestions on other similar posts but none of them seem to be the answer (e.g. version of virtualenv, latest python, uninstalling and reinstalling virtualenv, etc). Not sure if there is an easy way to change the sys.prefix issue?

Comment: I have also tried the suggestions (other than the answer that suggested painstakingly scraping through all potential python versions) on the suggested duplicate post, including trying to create it in a different folder.